# Generating a basic ledger report in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a sample account transaction table like this:

```
VchNo   TranDate    Credits     Debits
PR1    07 Dec 2011  10000.50      0.00
PI1    13 Dec 2011  26000.00      0.00
PI2    14 Dec 2011  15841.50      0.00
PR2    15 Dec 2011  9845.25       0.00
PL1    31 Dec 2011     0.00   58741.25
PJ3    02 Jan 2012     0.00    1021.00
```

and I know the opening balances of this account

```
Opening Balance: 99825.00
```

I wish to generate a basic ledger report like this by showing the opening and closing balances for each of the transactions mentioned above, like this:

```
VchNo  TranDate     Opening       Credits    Debits   Closing
PR1   07 Dec 2011   99825.00    10000.50      0.00  109825.50
PI1   13 Dec 2011   109825.50   26000.00      0.00  135825.50
PI2   14 Dec 2011   135825.50   15841.50      0.00  151667.00
PR2   15 Dec 2011   151667.00   9845.25       0.00  161512.25
PL1   31 Dec 2011   161512.25      0.00   58741.25  102771.00
PJ3   02 Jan 2012   102771.00      0.00    1021.00  101750.00
```

In the above table, closing = opening + Credits - Debits
Closing of today is the opening for next day (subsequent day).
The closing balance obtained in 101750.00 (refer to last column for VchNo PJ3).

I have attached a sample report format for quick reference [image: Ledger Report].
 Is it possible to achieve this using a SINGLE SQL query?

Comment: Where does your initial Opening figure come from? Are you limited to SQL Server 2005, or could you use a later edition, such as 2008?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 is the only version I'm using. The opening amount could come from another query, which I've not shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(vchno NVARCHAR(6)
,trandate DATETIME
,credits DECIMAL(18,3)
,debits DECIMAL(18,3)
,opening DECIMAL(18,3)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
SELECT 'PR1'as vchno,'07 Dec 2011'as trandate,10000.50 as credits,0.00 as debits,99825 AS opening
UNION ALL SELECT 'PI1' ,'13 Dec 2011' ,  26000.00 ,  0.00,99825  
UNION ALL SELECT 'PI2','14 Dec 2011',  15841.50,  0.00 ,99825
UNION ALL SELECT 'PR2','15 Dec 2011',  9845.25 ,  0.00 ,99825
UNION ALL SELECT 'PL1','31 Dec 2011', 0.00 ,  58741.25 ,99825
UNION ALL SELECT 'PJ3','02 Jan 2012', 0.00,1021.00 ,99825

;With ledger AS
(
SELECT vchno
,trandate
,opening
,credits
,debits
,opening + credits - debits AS closing
,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY trandate) AS row
FROM #data
)
SELECT
l1.vchno
,l1.trandate
,MAX(l1.opening) + ISNULL(SUM(l2.credits),0) - ISNULL(SUM(l2.debits),0) as opening
,MAX(l1.credits) AS issues
,MAX(l1.debits) AS Receips
,MAX(l1.opening) + ISNULL(SUM(l2.credits),0) - ISNULL(SUM(l2.debits),0) + MAX(l1.credits) - MAX(l1.debits) as closing
FROM ledger l1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ledger l2 on l2.row < l1.row
GROUP BY
l1.vchno
,l1.trandate
```